# Load Video to flow player in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flowplayer

I need to add a flow player to my MVC website. i have added a video to server. when i directly put src path in tag it shows **video file not found**

```
<div class="flowplayer">
     <video>
        <source type="video/mp4"  src="my server file location">
     </video>
</div>
```

In site.Master head file i have added

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- 1. skin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/skin/minimalist.css">

    <!-- 2. jquery library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 3. flowplayer -->
    <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

But when i run this it gets
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with a video from one of the demos on the flowplayer site first.

It may be the video is either encoded incorrectly or the web browser that you tried it on does not support that format.

[HTML5 browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support)